# Jquery - multiple dropdown lists, disable selected entry in other lists

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

I've got multiple dropdown lists, when I select an entry in one I want it to be disabled in other so it can't be selected.

But if it is deselected, then I need it available in the other lists.

So far I've got:

```
$('#frm1').on('change', 'select[name="dropdown"]', function (event) {   

    $('.dropdown').not(this).find('option[value="' + dropdownval + '"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

});
```

Which does disable a selected entry in other lists, but I can't see how to revert that if it's de selected.

This is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90ndp12o/2/)** showing what I've got so far.

Any ideas
Thanks

Comment: Please include you html

Comment: link to fiddle added to original post.

Comment: If selection of an option should clear any previous disabled affect then add a command to select all options and clear the disabled value as the first line in the event handler. Something like  $('.dropdown.option').attr('disabled',''); - note I have not tested this selector but it should be close.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#frm1').on('change', 'select[name="dropdown"]', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown option').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
      var v = $(this).val();
      if (v != "") {
        $('.dropdown').not(this).find("option[value='" + v + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#frm1').on('change', 'select[name="dropdown"]', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown option').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
      var v = $(this).val();
      if (v != "") {
        $('.dropdown').not(this).find("option[value='" + v + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='frm1'>

  <select name="dropdown" class='dropdown'>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
  <select name="dropdown" class='dropdown'>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
  <select name="dropdown" class='dropdown'>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
  <select class="dropdown" class='dropdown'>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks - this does exactly what I needed.